# Rails 4 chain conditions with ranges and or

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

The syntax in rails 4 evolves, but it is not clear how to adapt to multiple conditions, particularly with ranges. So

```
Circuit.where(origin_lon: (@lng_min.to_f..@lng_max.to_f), origin_lat: (@lat_min.to_f..@lat_max.to_f))
```

with its commas, does an `AND` query.  However, if one wants to add another `AND` clause which is made up of two `OR` conditions, [the api QueryMethods instructions do not clear up](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html) how to write this:

```
Circuit.where(origin_lon: (@lng_min.to_f..@lng_max.to_f), origin_lat: (@lat_min.to_f..@lat_max.to_f), ('when_start >= ? OR when_end <= ?', @earliest_start, @latest_start) )
```

leads to a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix SQL-style `where` conditions with pure-ruby `where` conditions. You need to split the `where`.

```
Circuit.where(origin_lon: @lng_min.to_f..@lng_max.to_f, origin_lat: @lat_min.to_f..@lat_max.to_f).where('when_start >= ? OR when_end <= ?', @earliest_start, @latest_start)
```

You can also use scopes to cleanup a little bit the syntax and make the code more reusable

```
class Circuit < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :longitude, ->(min, max) { where(origin_lon: min.to_f..max.to_f) }
  scope :latitude, ->(min, max) { where(origin_lat: min.to_f..max.to_f) }
end

Circuit.longitude(@lng_min, @lng_max).latitude(@lat_min, @lat_max).where('when_start >= ? OR when_end <= ?', @earliest_start, @latest_start)
```

Comment: OK. `.where[...].where` clears some confusion...  what if the second where statement were an `ÒR` for a range?

Comment: You can combine all in a single `where` using the SQL-like syntax.